# How to parse clob data in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing, plsql, clob

I need to parse clob data in oracle.I want to find best practices.It might be procedure or function or script.What can I do for solving this problem?

[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF5rr.png),

[Clob Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBAZU.png),

[Parsed Results Table should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37mF9.png)

Comment: have a look at the JSON_TABLE function which is available from 12.1 onwards. You shouldn't have to do any parsing yourself - JSON_TABLE does exactly that: convert a json object to rows.

Comment: The `JSON_TABLE` function only returns values, not the keys. PL/SQL will be needed if B1, B2, B3 are needed in the result.

Comment: @EJEgyed I search to json path exp.I found "$.*~" exp to get key. but it's not working. I decided to use ref cursor and fuction. Firstly split " , " then  " : ". What could be return type? I dont want to create new table. but The results should be table. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

My first option will be JSON_TABLE if you have Oracle version >= 12.1 but this is an alternative option I ab(use) time to time

```
with a as (
            select 'ID01' AS ID,'"A1":{"B1":"C1"},"A2":{"B2":"C2"},"A3":{"B3":"C3"}' AS B FROM DUAL
            UNION
            select 'ID02' AS ID,'"B1":{"C1":"D1"},"B2":{"C2":"D2"},"B3":{"C3":"D3"}' AS B FROM DUAL
            union
            select 'ID03' AS ID,'"tablex":{"Cola":"colb"},"B2":{"C2":"D2"}' AS B FROM DUAL 
          )
SELECT CLOBID,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(CLOB_D,'"(.+?)"',1,1,null,1) AS Col1,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(CLOB_D,'"(.+?)"',1,2,null,1) AS Col2,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(CLOB_D,'"(.+?)"',1,3,null,1) AS Col3
FROM(
select ID AS CLOBID,LEVEL,REGEXP_COUNT(B,'\,',1), regexp_substr(B,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL,NULL) CLOB_D
FROM A
CONNECT BY (LEVEL - 1) <= REGEXP_COUNT(B,'\,',1)
AND ID = PRIOR ID
AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() IS NOT NULL
);
```